# Is there a way to read the numbers on consecutive specific lines in C++?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, vector, text

Let's assume I have a program which takes as an input a file
(numbers.in)
which contains on the first line a number n, on the second line n numbers separated using a space, and on the third line, some other n numbers separated by a space.

**I do know how much n is, for I read it form the first line. I don not know how to jump on the second line and read ONLY the numbers on that line, then to thew third etc.**

I want to save the numbers on the second line in a vector A in the same order they are on that line and in a vector B the numbers on the third line, as shown. So far I have this:

```
    #include <stream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    ifstream fin("numbers.in");
    ofstream fout("result.out");
    int main()
    {  int N;
    string line;
    fin>>N;
    long long A[N];
    unsigned long long B[N];
    for(int i=0; i<=N-1; i++)
    {  
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            A[i]=getline(fin, );
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=N-1; i++)
    {  
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            B[i]=getline(fin, );
        }
    }
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

By writing code to do so.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
std::ifstream fin("numbers.in");
std::ofstream fout("result.out");
int main()
{
    int N;
    // read the number of numbers
    fin>>N;
    // allocate vectors for storing numbers
    std::vector<long long> A(N);
    std::vector<unsigned long long> B(N);
    // read N numbers
    for(int i=0; i<=N-1; i++)
    {
        fin>>A[i];
    }
    // read another N numbers
    for(int i=0; i<=N-1; i++)
    {
        fin>>B[i];
    }
}
```

The loop `for(int i=0; i<=N-1; i++)` is not bad, but `for(int i=0; i<N; i++)` is the common way, at least in my view.

Comment: Ok. But the numbers for B(i) or B[i] as recommended in the project are on the NEXT line.

For example, in the text file there could be:

```
    4  (the number N)
    3 6 98 220 (numbers I want in A)
    4 6 12 443 (numbers I want in B)
```

Comment: I haven't used operator>> for this kind of thing yet, but I would guess that it just ignores whitespace. And newlines ('\n') are also whitespace.

Comment: If we already specify common loopform, I would go for ++i. In optimised (production) binaries it doesn't make a difference, but w/o optimization (e.g. debug builds) i++ actually saves the old i and therefore adds instructions. It's in most cases probably insignificant, but I would say that it's a good habit.

Comment: @Paul thanks for the tip, but the project is on another topic. I'll do so from now on, with ++i, but I need help with the vector part. Especially a full section of code, not just instructions here and there, scattered all across the page. I need 5 coherent lines of code.

Comment: @AndrewFNAF operator>> will move to the next line if it needs to.